# Removing unwanted symbols from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array that returns the following:

```html
["↵Onprogress↵Done"]
```

I want to remove this symbol: '↵'.

I've tried all sorts of stuff, as you can see in the code below. I tried calling a variable to the value of the arrow filtering the variable from the array. Or declaring a second empty array and then iterating over the first one and pushing what I want to the second array. I'm starting to wonder whether this is something that the console returns by default? Would highly appreciate if some can help me out. Please also keep in mind that when I return the array by index it gives me 'undefined'.

```html
    addCardtoApp = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const card = {
            taskName: this.taskName.current.value, 
            taskDescription: this.taskDescription.current.value,
            taskPeriod: this.taskPeriod.current.value,
        };
        const cardStatus = this.taskStatus.current.value;
        let otherStatus = {
            otherStatus: this.taskStatus.current.innerText,
        };
        // otherStatus = otherStatus.otherStatus.replace('↵', '');
        const replacedStatus = otherStatus.otherStatus.replace(`${cardStatus}`, '');
        const convertedStatus = replacedStatus.split(' ');
        // let annoyingArrow = '↵'
        // console.log('↵')
        // let refinedStatus = convertedStatus
        // refinedStatus = refinedStatus.filter( item => item !== 'Todos' || 'Onprogress' || 'Done');
        let refinedStatus = []
        convertedStatus.forEach(function(item) {
            if (item === 'Todos' || 'Onprogress' || 'Done') { refinedStatus.push(item) };
        })
        console.log(refinedStatus);
        this.props.addCard(card, cardStatus, refinedStatus);
        event.currentTarget.reset();
    };
```

Comment: Lots of stuff going on here. Could you post the starting state of the data (`["↵Onprogress↵Done"]` ?) and the desired end result (`["Onprogress", "Done"]`, or something else?)?

Comment: Hello, yes the desired end result is ["Onprogress", "Done"]

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I've added an answer that returns that result.

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = ["↵Onprogress↵Done"];
const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/↵/g, ''));
```

Comment: This code doesn't run. `const new array = ...` is not valid JavaScript.

I get what you're doing with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr).replace...`, and it should work fine, but it would be more efficient to use `arr.map(...`. Stringifying and parsing are relatively expensive operations.

Comment: Mis-typed the `newArray` const. I would easily challenge running a strigify and parse and one replace on a large array vs a map and a replace on every element in the array ;)

Comment: - on small arrays, you're splitting hairs.

Answer (score 1):

Some consoles represent a line break (`\n`) as that symbol (↵). To remove them from a string, you can do this:

```js
// remove first instance
yourString.replace('\n', '')

// remove all instances
yourString.replace(/\n/g, '')
```

EDIT:

If you need to only remove leading or trailing characters, you can use regex beginning/end indicators. e.g.

```js
// remove the first newline at the *beginning* of the string
yourString.replace(/^\n/, '')

// remove *any* newlines at the *beginning* of the string
yourString.replace(/^\n*/, '')

// remove any newlines at the *end* of the string
yourString.replace(/\n*$/, '')
```

Comment: Remove **first** instance

Comment: @Chris Deacy, thanks. But now i'm removing characters I need inside the item in my array. How can run this function to remove the only the \n before the word itself?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, you were on the right track with this:

`// otherStatus = otherStatus.otherStatus.replace('↵', '');`

I believe your issue was that you have two `↵` in your string, and your usage of `replace` will only replace the first one. The second one will still be there. Use regex instead to replace all of them:

`otherStatus.otherStatus.replace(/↵/g, '');`

More information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp):

> Note: If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier (see "More Examples" below).

Answer (score 0):

By splitting on the character you don't want, you can break up the string and remove the character at the same time.

```
>> (["↵Onprogress↵Done"])[0].split(/↵/).filter(Boolean)
[ "Onprogress", "Done" ]
```

Comment: Hi @Jake  This doesn't work because the item in the array is one big string.

Comment: @AlyDabbous could you clarify that statement a bit? I copied the input in my answer directly from the question.